# Reading null values from Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I'm using this to read all values from an Excel column:

```
            Range columnToRead = ws.UsedRange.Columns[columnIndex];
            System.Array myValues = (System.Array)columnToRead.Cells.Value;
            List<String> myListValues = myValues.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList<String>();
            myListValues.RemoveAt(0);    //remove header
```

It works fine.

However I notice that empty cells are ignored/skipped.

What should I do if I want a `""` to be added to my List when a cell is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `.OfType<object>()` as it will only return the objects that it casts as object (which will ignore the nulls).

You probably need to shift all the items into another list or something, like this:

```
Range columnToRead = ws.UsedRange.Columns[columnIndex];
System.Array myValues = (System.Array)columnToRead.Cells.Value;

var output = new List<object>();
foreach (var a in myValues ){output.Add(a);}

List<String> myListValues = output.Select(o => o == null ? String.Empty : o.ToString()).ToList<String>();
myListValues.RemoveAt(0);    //remove header
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But `output.OfType<object>()` will ignore the null from `output` too since you mentioned `.OfType<object>()` will ignore the nulls.

Answer (score -2):

```
IF(ISBLANK(A1),1,0)
```

can be used to check if a cell is blank or not.
This returns 1 if cell is blank and 0 otherwise.

Moreover if you want to ignore white spaces you can use

```
IF(ISBLANK(A1),TRUE,(TRIM(A1)=""))
```